# Connecting Google App Engine with Javascript client

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine

I have a diagram editor application (client), which is written in javascript. I need to take the model of the diagrams (can be transformed to text), and synchronise it with my GAE Java application which will be my backend. The application will then store this model on cloud, or send it to other clients. (as a result many people work on same diagrams)

This is a totally new field to me, and even though I completed some of the tutorials google provides, and gone through documentation, I am not sure how the connection will be done (tutorials used JSP).

> What is the most straight- forward approach into connecting a Java 
>   application (GAE)  with a JS client ?

p.s: I have read about ajax, but I dont know if its the right solution for this, or if there is a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the most straight- forward approach into connecting a Java
>   application (GAE) with a JS client ?

Through an API built on HTTP.  Your JAVA web app can expose certain endpoints.  You can then use Javascript to make http requests, (through AJAX) to your java web api).  This is currently the defacto way of communicating from front end with javascript to any backend service.

There will be some trickiness to supporting real time collaboration between clients.

Additionally, there has been increasing support for [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/), which allows you to open a persistant connection between your client and your server, i don't know if java on GAE supports it though...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just checked about websockets. They arent supported for GAE although it provides an API that fills same role:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/

Comment: While the answer is straightforward (ajax call to servlet) what you *really* want to do is use the drive realtime api so you can have multiple concurrent users exiting your models plus lots more that api gives you (revisions sharing etc)

Comment: I had not looked on drive api before, I thought I would need google cloud storage. Thanks for the pointer